# behat.yml in app/config instead of root directory

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, behat, mink

I installed behat with mink and selenium2-driver for my Symfony2 project.

Is it possible to use the `/app/config/behat.yml` instead of the `/behat.yml` file?

I searched on google but I can't find anything else this command.

```
php bin/behat --config app/config/behat.yml
```

But the command isn't working either.
I think there must be a config-path in composer.json.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can configure which config file you want to use. Look at this part of the doc.
http://docs.behat.org/guides/7.config.html#paths

What error do you get when running your command?

```
php bin/behat --config app/config/behat.yml
```

This error?

```
[RuntimeException]                                                         
Context class not found.                                                   
Maybe you have provided a wrong or no `bootstrap` path in your behat.yml:  
http://docs.behat.org/guides/7.config.html#paths
```

If that's the case, I think if might be because you need to specify where to find the features in your behat.yml file.

Now you moved the file to /app/config/behat.yml, the related path from behat.yml to the feature directory has changed, so you should add the following to the file:

```
default:
    paths:
         features: ../features/
         bootstrap: ../features/bootstrap
```

Comment: It's not possible to run the command without `--config app/config/behat.yml`?

Comment: Yes, it also works. By default behat looks for a file behat.yml in the root directory of the project or in config/behat.yml.
But the path from the behat.yml to the feature directory would still be broken, so you still need to edit the path inside the file.

Comment: Doesn't work... I'm in `/var/www`, the `behat.yml` is in `/var/www/app/config/behat.yml` and the binary is in `/var/www/bin/behat`. The config contains `default:
    paths:
        features: ../features
        bootstrap: ../features/asd` (i renamed the bootstrap directory to asd for test)

Comment: Try using `%behat.paths.base%/../../features`

Comment: Doesnt work, too.... The problem is that behat ignore the app/config/behat.yml file! If i write "test" in the file (no yaml format) and execute `php bin/behat --config app/config/behat.yml` i get this `Unable to parse in "app\/config\/behat.yml" at line 2 (near "test").`
But if i use `php bin/behat` i get `Context class not found.`.

Because that behat ignores the behat.yml.